# Prove projection of $v$ onto a subspace is the one with minmum distance to $v$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over field $F$, and $V$ can be decomposed as a direct sum $V = {V_1} \oplus {V_2}$ of two subspaces $V_1$ and $V_2$, then any vector $\bf v$ can be uniquely written as ${\bf v}={\bf v}_1+{\bf v}_2$ for some ${\bf v}_1\in V_1$, ${\bf v}_2\in V_2$. We define ${\bf v}_1$ as the projection of $\bf v$ into subspace $V_1$, denoted by ${\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}{\mathbf{v}} = {{\mathbf{v}}_1}$.

The projection is unique since the direct sum decomposition of $\bf v$ is unique.

My question is how to prove

> ${\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}{\mathbf{v}} = {\arg _{\mathbf{u}}}\mathop {\min }\limits_{{\mathbf{u}} \in {V_1}} \left\| {{\mathbf{u}} - {\mathbf{v}}} \right\|$, where $\|\|$ is any norm. In plain words, ${\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}{\mathbf{v}}$ is the vector in $V_1$ that is nearest to $\bf v$ w.r.t. any norm.

I think the proof should not be hard. but an attempt of using triangular inequality does not seem to give me anything,
$\left\| {{\mathbf{u}} - {\mathbf{v}}} \right\| = \left\| {{\mathbf{u}} - {{\mathbf{v}}_1} - {{\mathbf{v}}_2}} \right\| \leqslant \left\| {{\mathbf{u}} - {{\mathbf{v}}_1}} \right\| + \left\| {{{\mathbf{v}}_2}} \right\|$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not** true that if $V = V_1 \oplus V_2$, then ${\operatorname{proj}_{{V_1}}}{\mathbf{v}} = {\arg _{\mathbf{u}}}\mathop {\min }\limits_{{\mathbf{u}} \in {V_1}} \left\| {{\mathbf{u}} - {\mathbf{v}}} \right\|$.  As a counterexample: take $\|\cdot\|$ to be the typical Euclidean norm (i.e. the "$\ell^2$ norm").  We may say that $V = \Bbb R^2$ can be decomposed as $V_1 \oplus V_2$ where $V_1 = \operatorname{span}\{(1,0)\}$ and $V_2 = \operatorname{span}\{(1,1)\}$ (so $V_1$ is the $x$-axis and $V_2$ the line $y = x$).

We find, for instance, that $\operatorname{proj}_{{V_1}}(0,1) = (-1,0)$ since $(0,1) = (-1,0) + (1,1)$.  However, it is clear that $(0,0) \in V_1$ is closer to $(0,1)$ than the so-called "projection".