# Approximation problem with two vectors belonging to row space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

The given approximation problem is given $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $\vec{x},\vec{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ find $\vec{y}$ such that it is a solution $A\vec{y}=\vec{0}$ and it is a minimum distance from $\vec{x}$

I need help proving that if $A\vec{y}=\vec{0}$ and $||\vec{x}-\vec{y}||$ is minimized, then $$\vec{x}-\vec{y}\in Row(A)$$
So far I have that $\vec{y}\in Null(A)$ but I'm having trouble on where I need to go from there. I know I need to do something with the Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra, but I can not see what I need to do now.

Comment: Think about projecting $\vec{x}$ onto $Null(A)$...

Comment: Should I construct some arbitrary basis for $Null(A)$ when computing the projection. If so, I still don't know what I can say about the inner product between $\vec{x}$ and the basis vectors of $Null(A)$

Comment: No need for that. What I was suggesting is that $p(\vec{x})=\vec{y}$. Can you see why?

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that $||\vec{x}-\vec{y}||$ is minimized but I'm unsure as to what that truly means. Also, when you write $p(\vec{x})$, are you referring to $proj_{Null(A)}(\vec{x})$

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304079/show-orthogonal-projection-is-minimal-distance?noredirect=1&lq=1. Sorry for the notations, I'm typing on my phone...

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. So we have $||\vec{x}-\vec{y}||>||\vec{x}-proj_{Null(A)}\vec{v}||$. So does that automatically imply that $||\vec{x}-proj_{Null(A)}\vec{v}||\in (Null(A))^\perp = Row(A)$? Or am I missing something else

Comment: Realising that $\vec{y}=proj_{Null(A)}(\vec{x})$ means that if you decompose $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R^n}=Null(A)\bigoplus Row(A)$ you immediately get $||\vec{x}-proj_{Null(A)}\vec{v}||\in (Null(A))^\perp = Row(A)$.